# Printing list of dictionaries in Python to .csv in unique rows

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, export-to-csv

I currently have a list that contains 6 dictionaries, but plan on expanding to ~1000 dictionaries in this single list. Each dictionary has the same 9 keys, which I hope to be my column headers. For certain keys, the value is a string, such as a city name, while for other keys, the value is a list, which may differ in length for each dictionary (such as hobbies).

A shortened example, with just 3 keys per dictionary (name, city, hobbies):

`list_of_dictionaries = [{'name' : 'John', 'city' : 'Las Vegas', 'hobbies' : ['running', 'gambling', 'weight-lifting']}, {'name' : 'Jane', 'city' : 'Chicago', 'hobbies' : ['video games', 'yoga']}, {'name' : 'Jack', 'city' : 'New York', 'hobbies' : ['sports', 'drinking', 'travel', 'fashion']}]`

I would like to print this list of dictionaries to a CSV, with each permutation of key-value pair in a separate row, like in the following format:

> Name City Hobbies
>
> John Las Vegas Running
>
> John Las Vegas Gambling
>
> John Las Vegas Weight-Lifting
>
> Jane Chicago Video Games
>
> Jane Chicago Yoga
>
> Jack New York Sports
>
> Jack New York Drinking
>
> Jack New York Travel
>
> Jack New York Fashion

I am relatively new to Python/programming and realize I may be taking a very inefficient approach. I have tried the csv module, DictWriter, etc, and nothing has produced the desired result. I am open to anything, whether it simply be a module, or reworking the list/dictionaries. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

edit: The six dictionaries come from the six files I am iterating over. So for each file, I have nine strings/lists, and I am combining together as a dictionary, and then appending the six dictionaries together in one list.

James

Comment: Is Hobbies the only multi-length value out of the 9 keys? Or are there other keys that have repeating values?

Comment: There are other ones. 6 are strings, 3 are multi-length values. In each iteration they will be of the same length. For example, (hobbies, level of interest, activities per month).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using csv:

```
import csv

list_of_dictionaries = [
{'name' : 'John', 'city' : 'Las Vegas', 'hobbies' : ['running', 'gambling', 'weight-lifting']},
{'name' : 'Jane', 'city' : 'Chicago', 'hobbies' : ['video games', 'yoga']},
{'name' : 'Jack', 'city' : 'New York', 'hobbies' : ['sports', 'drinking', 'travel', 'fashion']}
]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv = csv.writer(
        csvfile,
        delimiter=',',
        quotechar='"',
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
    )

    csv.writerow(['Name','City','Field1','Field2','...'])

    for item in list_of_dictionaries:
        # Include any multi-value fields as:
        # for field1, field2, ... in zip(item['field1', 'field2', ...]):
        #    csv.writerow([item['name'], item['city'], field1, field2, ...])
        for hobby in item['hobbies']:
            csv.writerow([item['name'], item['city'], hobby])
```

**Edit:**
To allow for any number of multi-valued fields.

Comment: Great, thank you, trying this now with my inputted code

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps... write your own csv writer...

```
for element in list_of_dictionaries:
for i in range(len(element['hobbies'])):
    print("{0} {1} {2}".format(element['name'],element['city'],element['hobbies'][i]))
```